# Need a Reg Expression to find a decimal range

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently needing a reg expression which will evaluate a decimal range.

The requirements are as below

1) Can allow only 1 or 2 decimal places after dot or can as well allow whole numbers (e.g) 1234 , 123.4, 1245.78 are valid

2) The range should be within 9999 (e.g) 9999.0 , 9998.99 , 9999.00 - Valid |  9999.01,10000.00 -  not Valid

3)Do not require leading or trailing zeros

So far i have tried to achieve till writing this reg expression

```
/^[0-9]\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(value);
```

... but unable to proceed with setting range till digit 9999 (since 9999.01 also not valid )can you help.

Comment: use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test your regular expression. Its easy to use and does not require running any script :)

Comment: As far as I can tell (and test), 9999.01 is a good value that passes the regex.

Comment: @webbandit - This says 9999.01 is valid, which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just apply regular expression to determine is your string a valid `digit with dots` float, then typecast it to Number and find wether it is bigger than 9999 or not.

Regexp for your needs caould be very complex and take too much CPU from client.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something quick and dirty that should work for you: http://regex101.com/r/vK1jM3

`/^(?(?=9999)9999(?:\.0+)?|\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/gm`

I merely handle the special case of `9999`

Comment: Hi when i use this above exp it says .. invalid quantifier.. dont know what is the problem

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that javascript might not support conditional statements...

Answer (score 0):

This works as far as I can see:

```
^(9999(?!\.[1-9])(?!\.0[1-9])\.[0-9]{1,2}|9999|(?!9999)[0-9]{1,4}|(?!9999)[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,2})$
```

Testing it out:

```
var monstrosity = /^(9999(?!\.[1-9])(?!\.0[1-9])\.[0-9]{1,2}|9999|(?!9999)[0-9]{1,4}|(?!9999)[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,2})$/;

console.log(monstrosity.test("9999.00")); // true
console.log(monstrosity.test("9999.01")); // false
console.log(monstrosity.test("9999")); // true
console.log(monstrosity.test("9998.4")); // true
console.log(monstrosity.test("0")); // true
console.log(monstrosity.test("0.5")); // true
```

If you add something like this to the codebase, future maintenance programmers will hunt you down with pitchforks.  Try to solve the range check without regex, as webbandit suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why a regexp? Just do

```
x > 0 && x <= 9999 && (x*100 - Math.floor(x*100) == 0)
```

Comment: If you are referring to 9999 itself, I edited the answer to use `<=` instead of '<'.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been drunk.  Can't see any problems with it.